# How to change product by a storeview in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

In the backend you can set different settings for a product by a storeview.
But how can you get those products by a storeview.
Getting a product could be done like this, but how to get the product data from a different storeview

```
 $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer here uses the ObjectManager directly and the deprecated load function, so for a more best-practices approach you can use the ProductRepositoryInterface to load product within a specific store scope.

After injecting an instance of ProductRepositoryInterface (e.g. called $_productRepository) into your class, use the following with $storeId set to the ID of your desired store view.

```
$oProduct = $_productRepository->get('mysku',false, $storeId, false);
```

Or to fetch by ID:

```
$oProduct = $_productRepository->getById($productId,false, $storeId, false);
```

Comment: I would have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14732149) and see the recommended change Luca made. Your function to fetch by ID may be wrong.

Comment: @FrankerZ so why you rejected it? Matt O function to fetch by ID is wrong 100%, i tested it and it has to be getById(), just see `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface.php`

Comment: @LucaS See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164449/295637) answer.

Comment: Edited to correct the function name - thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 0):

Use `->setStoreId(0)`

**Single product**

To load a single product by storeview use this code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId(0)->load($product->getId());
```

**Product collection**

To load multiple products by a storeview, you could use the product collection like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$collection = $productCollection->create()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->setStoreId(0)
              ->load();
```

---

Change in `->setStoreId(0`) the `0` to your storeview ID

Use store id `0` to change te product default data